# How to I instantiate a class with an initial value?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this script, and i want to pass one value from the loop to My_Class:

```
class My_Class(multiprocessing.Process):

    def run(self):
        print 'Hello from a class'
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(100):
        process = My_Class()
        process.start()
```

exemple : Hello from a class 1;
how can make this ?

Comment: What do you want to do here?  Neither your code nor your question is clear as to your intent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems you are missing a call to the super class in your init. Although I'm not exactly sure what the use case here would be, this code works for me:

```
import multiprocessing


class My_Class(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        super(My_Class, self).__init__()
        self.v = initial_value

    def run(self):
        print 'Hello from a class ' + str(self.v)
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(100):
        process = My_Class(x)
        process.start()
```

Comment: im trying use queue, i have this script : http://pastebin.com/PqAwGqMB
where is my error ? can help me ?

Comment: Does the accepted answer not satisfy your questions?  If it doesn't then you shouldn't have accepted it -- or you should be asking a new different question.

Answer (score -2):

```
class My_Class(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, initial_value):
        super(My_Class, self).__init__()
        v=initial_value

    def run(self):
        print 'Hello from a class '+self.v
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in range(100):
        process = My_Class(x)
        process.start()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/PYTHON/scanner-multiprocessing/multiprocessing_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    process.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 120, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
AttributeError: 'My_Class' object has no attribute '_popen'

Comment: I cannot debug the entire program for you. this is a completely different issue, and you need to search StackOverflow for the correct answer, and if you don't find it (which I doubt), you can ask a different question

Comment: root@kali:~/Desktop# python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    Process.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 120, in start
    assert self._popen is None, 'cannot start a process twice'
AttributeError: 'My_Class' object has no attribute '_popen'

Comment: Also, please make `v = inital_value` into `self.v` or `self.inital_value` `= inital_value`. It's a variable of the class!